# Flutter BottomAppBar with specific shape

Tags: flutter

Could you suggest my how to implement BottomAppBar with shape as you could see in picture bellow

[image]

I'm trying to wrap BottomAppBar with ClipRRect

```
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
    top: Radius.circular(40),
  ),
  child: BottomAppBar(
    key: widget.key,
    shape: widget.notchedShape,
    child: Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: items,
    ),
    color: Colors.red, //widget.backgroundColor,
  ),
);
```

But result is not as I wish

Comment: You can make your own/custom shape using `CustomPainter()`

Comment: Thanks, but how to apply this class to BottomAppBar

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CustomPainter()` and using that you can make your own design.
This is not perfect as you have shown by you but you can always tweak the setting on your own.

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(size.width * 0.0500000, size.height * 0.9000000);
    path_0.cubicTo(
        size.width * 0.5000000,
        size.height * 0.8400000,
        size.width * 0.4975000,
        size.height * 0.8380000,
        size.width * 0.9500000,
        size.height * 0.9000000);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(
        size.width * 1, size.height * 0.9, size.width, size.height);
    path_0.lineTo(0, size.height);
    path_0.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0, size.height * 0.90,
        size.width * 0.0500000, size.height * 0.9000000);
    path_0.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
    canvas.drawShadow(path_0, Color(0x68FFFFFF), 8, true);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Output
[image]